# Optimal process to append dynamically loaded items to Masonry

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am using Masonry and ImagesLoaded to prepare a grid layout where each item in the grid is a dynamically added image. Furthermore Infinite scroll is being used to add in items from subsequent pages on scroll (not manually triggered). Provided below is the structure of a grid item.

```
<article class="entry">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail-wrap">

  </a>
  <div class="entry-body">
   <div class="photo-wrap">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
   </div>
   <div class="photo-wrap">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
   </div>
   <div class="photo-wrap">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
   </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

The `<div class="entry-body"></div>` is hidden via CSS. The first image is added via JS inside the "thumbnail-wrap" container. To prevent throwing the grid off-balance when new content is loaded through Infinite Scroll the newly loaded elements are first hidden, the images then are dynamically added inside "thumbnail-wrap", next the items are appended to Masonry and after that the elements are shown. Below is the JS code used inside infinite scroll callback.

```
function(newElements){
  var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({
    opacity: 0
  });
  $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    // The first image being added
    $newElems.each( function() {
      var thumbnailImage = $(this).find('.entry-body .photo-wrap:first-child').html();
      $(this).find(".thumbnail-wrap").append(thumbnailImage);
    });
    // Newly loaded elements being appended
    $grid.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, { // var $grid = $('#content');
      isAnimated: false
      }, function(){
        $newElems.animate({
          opacity: 1
      });
    });
  });
```

By physically placing the code to dynamically add images before appending them to Masonry I am trying to prevent undue overlap of items. *My question is, if this is the most efficient way to go about the problem or is there any solution more optimal than that being used now?*

Any clarification in this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!